# How can I get rid of eth0:1?

Tags: connection

I issued the command `ifconfig` then it gave me 3 entries.
The first one is `eth0` the second one is `eth0:1` and `lo`.

Both `eth0` and `eth0:1` gave unique IP addresses, however I want to get rid of `eth0:1`. How do you think it can possibly be done?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Please add to your question the output from `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way to get rid of `eth0:1` is to enter:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:1 down
```

(If you are logged in via the IP address associated with `eth0:1`, your connection will drop at that point and you will have to log in again.)

`eth0:1` may come back after a reboot. Check `/etc/network/interfaces` to see if it defined in there.

Comment: yeap. exactly what I was looking for